# how do you skip uncomplete rows in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a huge file (2GB in size) with this:

```
data1<-read.table("file1.txt", sep=",",header=F)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 513836 did not have 8 elements
```

Is there a way to skip lines where missing data or replace it with NA values?

Comment: Try using `fill = TRUE` in `read.table`

Comment: Or try using `na.strings = "NA"` as an argument in your `read.table` function.

Comment: Not sure how `na.strings="NA"` will help here. It is to specify how the text file encodes `NA`s.

Comment: @RichardScriven, I will accept your answer, if you put it in an answer form. fill=True seems to be working.

Comment: You can also use `read.delim` or `read.csv` instead of `read.table`, which has some different default arguments, including `fill = TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is most commonly fixed by adding `fill = TRUE` to your `read.table()` call. In your case, it would be the following

```
data1 <- read.table("file1.txt", sep = ",", fill = TRUE)
```

Additionally, `header = FALSE` is the default setting for the header argument in `read.table()` and therefore unnecessary in your code.